# Laplace transform of $\int_0^t \frac{\cos{au} - \cos{bu}}{u} \, du$

Tags: laplace-transform

The question asks to find the Laplace transform of

$\int_0^t \frac{\cos{au} - \cos{bu}}{u} \, du$

I get stuck at

$ = \frac{1}{s} \left(\int_s^\infty \frac{u}{u^2+a^2}-\frac{u}{u^2+b^2}\, du \right)$

It says the answer is

$\frac{1}{s}ln{\frac{s^2+a^2}{s^2+b^2}}$

Could someone help?

Comment: I got to that point but I'm left with $\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{u^2 + a^2}{u^2+b^2}}\Big|_s^\infty$ am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: does that not then leave me with $-\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{s^2+a^2}{s^2+b^2}}$

Comment: Yes this is the result according to your working.